# Possible to deactiviate implicit commit on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, transactions

Is it possible to deactivate the implicit commit, which is called after create, drop ,rename, alter statements on Oracle Databases?

simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.test2x (id NUMBER(10,0));
ALTER TABLE TEST1.test2x ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

This will fail for the alter statement because the schema is wrong, but the table is now already created.
So is it somehow possible to bypass this behavior and only commit all or nothing, while using create, alter etc.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap an Oracle schema update in a transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303/wrap-an-oracle-schema-update-in-a-transaction) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730621/do-ddl-statements-always-give-you-an-implicit-commit-or-can-you-get-an-implicit?rq=1

Comment: No, you cannot make DDL transactional in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do "all-or-nothing" DDL but only in a very limited way -- the [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6014.htm) statement.

For example, the following `CREATE SCHEMA` statement tries to create two tables, `T1` and `T2`.  However, the DDL for `T2` is incorrect.  Neither table ends up getting created.

```
SQL> REM Verify the tables do not already exist.
SQL> SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T1
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> SELECT * FROM T2;
SELECT * FROM T2
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION TEST
  2      CREATE TABLE T1
  3      (
  4          X NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
  5      )
  6      CREATE TABLE T2
  7      (
  8          -- Try to reference a column that does not exist.
  9          X NUMBER REFERENCES T1(Y)
 10      );
        X NUMBER REFERENCES T1(Y)
                 *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-02428: could not add foreign key reference
ORA-00904: "Y": invalid identifier


SQL> REM Verify the tables still don't exist.
SQL> SELECT * FROM T1;
SELECT * FROM T1
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> SELECT * FROM T2;
SELECT * FROM T2
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

However, `CREATE SCHEMA` is limited in that it only supports `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW` and `GRANT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could run these commands inside of a plsql  "begin / end" block. Then catch and handle errors.

ie.

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table xyz (x number)';
  execute immediate 'alter table bad.xyz add';
exception
  when others then
    execute immediate 'drop table xyz';
end;
```